# The meaning of the bold part in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following text is written by an otherwise great writer who is a native speaker of English language. Nevertheless, I don't get the bold part. Is it written incorrectly?

> A special form of this requirement is that the belief has been
>   acquired in a reliable way. Thinking of a belief's being based on
>   grounds, this would amount to the requirement that the belief be based
>   on such grounds that forming beliefs like that on the basis of grounds
>   like that is a generally reliable way of forming beliefs, **one that
>   can be relied on provide mostly true beliefs**.

Answer (score 4):

I think it should read, "one that can be relied on **to** provide..."
"one" refers to "a generally reliable way of forming beliefs", so it means that such a way of forming beliefs can be trusted to provide correct beliefs (the truth?) most of the time.